# Cannot add a configuration with name 'androidJdkImage' as a configuration with that name already exists

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

This is my second question related to this android build issue.

I just updated gradle from 3.XX to 7.2.0 and am rebuilding and finding the following error.

Have i added 2 plugins that are inadvertently calling ths same configuration name by any chance. Any help will be appreciated.

**Error**

```
Build file '/home/mohit/Documents/Android project/paramg-android-app/app/build.gradle' line: 16

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
   > Cannot add a configuration with name 'androidJdkImage' as a configuration with that name already exists.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:366)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:393)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:365)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:366)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$withProjectLock$3(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.withProjectLock(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:426)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.D…
```

**App module build.gradle file:**

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    mavenCentral()
  

  }
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: '../dependencies.gradle'
        compileSdkVersion 32
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.paramg"
            minSdkVersion 22//18
            targetSdkVersion 32
            versionCode 32   // play stote 28
            versionName "1.1.24" //1.1.20
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
           // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    //        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    
    compileSdkVersion 32
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.paramg"
        minSdkVersion 22//18
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 32   // play stote 28
        versionName "1.1.24" //1.1.20
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
       // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
//        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries true
        dexInProcess = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    configurations {
        //noinspection DuplicatePlatformClasses
        compile.exclude group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", module: "httpclient"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/core_release.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.properties'
        pickFirst 'META-INF/maven/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            google()
            jcenter()
            url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"

        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
        abortOnError false
    }



    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    def version = "1.0.5"

    publish {
        userOrg = 'shinhyo'
        groupId = 'com.wonshinhyo'
        artifactId = 'dragrecyclerview'
        publishVersion = version
        website = 'https://github.com/adearya69/DragRecyclerView'
        issueTracker = "${website}/issues"
        repository = "${website}.git"
    }



}
dependencies {
// implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.3'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.3'
    implementation 'com.flurry.android:analytics:12.4.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.jgabrielfreitas:BlurImageView:1.0.1'
    implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.24'
    implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev181-1.22.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.9.0'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$archLifecycleVersion"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.9.0'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.2.2"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.9"
//    implementation project(':countrycodepicker')
    implementation 'com.github.takusemba:multisnaprecyclerview:1.3.4'
    implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.4.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1"
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.github.jgabrielfreitas:BlurImageView:1.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0") {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.gms"
    }
// implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:21.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:23.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1'

//    implementation project(':folioreader')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'

    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:11.0.1'
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.11.1"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.11.1"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.11.1"
    implementation "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.11.1"
    implementation 'com.tomergoldst.android:tooltips:1.0.10'

//progressBar error solve
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.3.2-5309881")
        }
    }
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'


//for auto read otp in android
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0-alpha01'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.0.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.10'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.0.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
    implementation 'com.github.SanojPunchihewa:InAppUpdater:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config-ktx:21.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.shts:StoriesProgressView:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.3llomi:CircularStatusView:V1.0.2'

    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.1'



    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.4.1"

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    annotationProcessor 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.4.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5.9'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.aar"])

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')





}


afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = "com.wwdablu"
                artifactId = "guidededittext"
                version = '1.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
//apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
googleServices { disableVersionCheck = true }
```

Comment: This question seems old, but anyway:
It seems like you have both application and library plugins. I had similar issue by occasion. Can you try to remove line `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` and try once more? I assume that this is the only module you have, so you should use application plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the build.gradle file in the project, pay attention not to the build. gradle in the app, Add apply false after id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1'.
eg.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same issue (at Gradle 8.1, 8.2), tried to put:

```
id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
```

also tried 8.1, 8.2

```
id 'com.android.library' version '8.1' apply false
id 'com.android.application' version '8.1' apply false
```

**but the problem had not resolved, until I had removed this plugin:**

```
id 'com.android.library'
```

Give it a try

```
plugins {
    //id 'com.android.library'
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

Comment: didnt work for me

Comment: please provide me more details, so I can help you, I need to see ur app/build.gradle, project/build.gradle

Comment: I straggled with the same issue when I tried to apply convention plugin to my application module, but forgot, that it has com.android.library under the hood. In this case the best strategy is create one more convention plugin